# How to get 100% height of column inside intel XDK

Tags: html, css, intel-xdk

Anyone else using Intel XDK and know how to manage columns to fit 100% of the screen? I can set the height in pixels but not in height, I've read the forums and seen that people with similar problems are supposed to add the height of all parent elements, i tried this without any further sucess. Any help or input highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use javascript/app framework to set the heights in a sizeIt() function that's called after the dom is fully loaded and on the resize event:

```
$(".fullheightdiv").css("height", window.innerHeight +"px");
```

If you have a header or footer just subtract their height from it like:

```
$(".divwithheader").css("height", window.innerHeight -40 +"px");
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks alot going to try this out tomorrow!

Comment: Works, do you know how to evenly spread buttons vertically within this column?(which is my final goal with this)

Comment: Does the number of buttons change?

Comment: nah they are the same, but i just managed to solve it now thanks to this technique, thanks alot once again

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new custom css class and set like this:

```css
.fullheight{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9j3l.png)